# Is $\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \iiint_V \iiint_V \left(\vec{J}\left(\vec{r}_1,t\right) \cdot \vec{J}_t\left(\vec{r}_2,t\right)\right) $ zero if...

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

In a finite volume $V \in \mathbb{R}^3$, there is a field  $\vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right)$. On the surface $\partial V$, $\vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right) = 0$.

The variable $\vec{r}$ represents position, and $t$ is, of course, time. Now say there are two time instants $t_1$ and $t_2$ such that for all $\vec{r} \in V$, $$\vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t_1\right) =\vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t_2\right)$$
Consider the following integral:
$$
   \int_{t_1}^{t_2} 
   \iiint_V
   \iiint_V
     \left[
      \vec{J}\left(\vec{r}_1,t\right) 
      \cdot 
      \frac {\partial \vec{J}\left(\vec{r}_2,t\right)} {\partial t}
     \right]
   \space dV\left(\vec{r}_1\right)
   \space dV\left(\vec{r}_2\right)
   \space dt
$$
Does this integral always evaluate to zero? Any proof?

Context: comes from classical electrodynamics, $\vec{J}$ is current density.

Comment: What is the difference between this question and the one you have asked and I have answered before? It is essentially the same question and hence same answer.

Comment: Hi @achille -- My earlier question was $$
   \int_{t_1}^{t_2}
   \left[ 
    \left(
     \iiint_V
      \vec{J}\left(\vec{r}_1,t\right) 
     \space dV\left(\vec{r}_1\right)
    \right)
   \cdot
    \left(
     \iiint_V
      \frac {\partial \vec{J}\left(\vec{r}_2,t\right)} {\partial t}
     \space dV\left(\vec{r}_2\right)
    \right)
   \right]
   \space dt
$$ Now instead of a (dot) product of two integrals, this is the integral of a dot product -- won't there be a difference? That's what I'm trying to grasp...

Comment: @achille -- OK, thanks, I get what you're saying. What I asked effectively is the continuous equivalent of $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)\cdot\left( \sum_{j=1}^n b_j\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n\left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_i \cdot b_j\right)$$ So it all works out.

Comment: Do you know [Fubini's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)? It basically says when your integrand is absolutely integrable, you can integrate your multiple integral in any order you want. Under that assumption, the continuous equivalent of what you think is valid.

Comment: Thanks @achille -- that was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just so this question doesn't stay 'unanswered', here's consolidating the answer(s) given by @achillehui (all credit for the answer go to him)

First, define:
$$\vec{Y}\left(t\right)=
   \iiint_V 
      \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right) 
   \space dV\left(\vec{r}\right)
$$
So $\vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t_1\right) = \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t_2\right)$
for all $\vec{r}\in V$
implies $\vec{Y}\left(t_1\right) = \vec{Y}\left(t_2\right)$ also.

By Fubini's theorem, the integral in the question becomes:
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}
   \left[ 
    \left(
     \iiint_V
      \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right) 
     \space dV\left(\vec{r}\right)
    \right)
   \cdot
    \left(
     \iiint_V
      \frac {\partial \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right)} {\partial t}
     \space dV\left(\vec{r}\right)
    \right)
   \right]
   \space dt
$$
Which becomes:
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}
   \left[ 
    \left(
     \iiint_V
      \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right) 
     \space dV\left(\vec{r}\right)
    \right)
   \cdot
    \left(
     \frac {d} {dt}
     \iiint_V
      \vec{J}\left(\vec{r},t\right)
     \space dV\left(\vec{r}\right)
    \right)
   \right]
   \space dt
$$
Which is:
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_2}
   \left[ 
    \vec{Y}\left(t\right)
   \cdot
    \left(
     \frac {d} {dt}
     \vec{Y}\left(t\right)
    \right)
   \right]
   \space dt
$$
Which is:
$$
\frac{1}{2} \left[|\vec{Y}(t)|^2\right]_{t1}^{t2}
$$
Which is zero because $\vec{Y}\left(t_1\right) = \vec{Y}\left(t_2\right)$